# Python Http Request not working in Pycharm IDE

Tags: python, http, ssl, pycharm, urllib

I'm going a bit crazy here and feel I must be missing something obvious.

I am trying to scrape data from a website using python and urllib3. My code looks like

```
>>> import urllib3
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>>
>>> http = urllib3.PoolManager()
>>> url = 'https://www.google.com/'
>>> r = http.request('GET', url)
>>> data = BeautifulSoup(r.data)
```

If I open up my terminal (I am on a mac), activate my conda virtual environment, then pull up the python interpreter this code works exactly as expected, pulling down the html request and parsing the data.

When I put the code into my Python IDE and set it to exactly the same virtual environment, the HTTP get request fails and I receive the following error

```
{MaxRetryError}HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.nts.live', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v2/shows/powell/episodes?offset=0&limit=12 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))
```

I have done similar requests in the past that have worked within Pycharm, so this is definitely user error at some stage. I am unsure what I should check other than that my virtual environment is the same? I have tried multiple different links and the issue persists. Any idea on why this error might be coming in would hugely appreciated!

Comment: Did you install [certifi](https://pypi.org/project/certifi/)?

Comment: Yeah, certifi is installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error comes not from the IDE but using the code within a module with other methods of retrieving http requests. The above lived in my `data_pull.py` file, however I had another file `spotify_request.py` that was also imported. Instead of urllib3, this file used `import requests` then `requests.get(url)`.

When I ran my code standalone in the terminal, this second import was never carried out and the code ran smoothly. To fix I replaced all urllib3 get requests with the requests library (https://pypi.org/project/requests/). I also tested by making all requests utilise urllib3 and the code ran fine too. I'm not sure WHY using both doesn't work but this has fixed my error.

TLDR; I was unable to use BOTH urllib3 and requests for http calls in my package - stick to one!